# Adding openSSL to Swift OS X project for receipt validation

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to include OpenSSL in a Swift OS X project for receipt validation.

I have successfully built the necessary OpenSSL header and library files.
I have added them to my project, but in doing so was not prompted to create a bridging header file.
I have created the bridging header file manually with #import for each of the openssl header files.
In the project build setting, I have set the objective C bridging header under "swift compiler - code generation" to my bridging header.
I have generated the ans1c files for the payload format as described in the receipt validation programming guide: "Listing 1-1 ASN.1 definition of the payload format" and added them to my bridging header.

I get numerous compile errors when I build, mainly for unknown type names in the openSSL header files which I would have thought would be defined in the ans1c header files, but they aren't.  I am also getting an error "Failed to import bridging header... (my bridging header file)".

I am running out of ideas, and may have to abandon openSSL for receipt validation.  If anyone knows what I am doing wrong, or if you have an alternate method for doing validation, I would love to hear it.  My app will have IAP, so it seems I would need some way of checking the receipt.

Comment: I believe I have isolated my current problem, but I don't know how to correct it.  I have built two bare bones projects into which I have imported the openSSL library and headers, one project in Swift and the other in Objective C.  With the objective C version I can build with no errors.  With the Swift version, the build results in multiple compiler errors, most being unknown type names for a few of the openSSL types.  When I bring the header files into the Swift project, I do not get prompted to make a bridging header, which makes me suspicious that I am not importing these correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally figured out the source of the compiler errors.  XCode is very picky about where the openssl headers are.  If I link directly to the header directory entitled "openssl" I get the compiler errors.  If I link to the parent folder entitled "include", no errors!

I do not understand this behavior, but at least now I have a solution.  Thanks to the instructions on [Receigen](http://receigen.etiemble.com/index.html) for [adding OpenSSL as a static library](http://receigen.etiemble.com/guides-openssl.html), which I finally followed precisely, I was able to discover the source of the error.

Comment: I have been batteling with this also, for any newbies, it turns out that in openssl 1.0.2a it is also necessary to adjust the openssl/rsa.h file to unlearn the "I" as defined in complex.h from the cocoa/foundation frameworks. This can be done by placing "#undef I" in the rsa.h file, just above "struct rsa_meth_st"

Comment: @jbaraga I am facing same issue openssl with swift. Please share solution with me.

Comment: It is finicky, but if you follow the instructions on Receigen precisely, it should work.  If not, you can try the instructions posted here: [link](http://swiftrien.blogspot.com/2015/05/osx-receipt-validation-in-swift-part-1.html).  I have not found it necessary to update the openssl/rsa.h file, as stated in those instructions, but it is worth a try if you continue to have problems.

Comment: Removing openssl and just using "include" worked for me as well, even though all tutorials say to include "openssl" in the path. Any idea why this fixes it? Just lost an hour dealing with this.

Comment: I don't know.  I have now added openSSL to two OS X projects and one iOS project, and each time it has been less than straightforward.  For the iOS project, I added the latest openSSL build posted on the Receigen site.  I had to rename the libcrypto.a file to lcrypto.a to make it work.

Comment: RE: “I had to rename the libcrypto.a file to lcrypto.a ”… Yes. I too got an error saying Xcode 7.3.1 could not find `lcrypto.a`. I followed [these instructions](http://receigen.etiemble.com/guides-openssl.html) using the OpenSSL-1.0.2g download from that page. So because of jbaraga’s comment, I duplicated the `libcrypto.a` file from that download, and renamed it. I replaced the added line item in `Link Binary With Libraries` to use this renamed file. Build then completed successfully. I am curious to know where the demand for `lcrypto.a` is coming from.